# Evaluating $\int x^x\ln(xe) \,\mathrm dx $

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

$$\int x^x\ln(xe) \,\mathrm dx $$
we got this problem so i seperated this as $\int x^x \ln(x) \,\mathrm dx $ + $\int x^x \ln(e)  \,\mathrm dx $
it becomes $\int x^x \ln(x)  \,\mathrm  dx$ + $\int x^x  \,\mathrm dx $ using $ \ln(ab) = \ln(a)+\ln(b) $ now what to do ? $x^x$ integration seems very difficult and so byparts integral can't be done in here , so so what to do ?

Answer (score 8):

$Hint: \frac{ \mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(x^{x})=x^{x}(\ln(x)+1)$

Comment: oh yeah that resolved it all , that's the answer

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$\int x^x\ln(xe) \,\mathrm dx=\int (e^{\ln x})^x (\ln x+\ln e ) \,\mathrm dx =\int e^{x\cdot\ln x}(\ln x+1) \,\mathrm dx$$

Put $x\cdot\ln x=u$